# Mongoose, trying to populate from same database, but different project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 API's that are located in the same database, but are created in different projects. Whenever I try to populate from one project to another, mongoose show an error "'Schema hasn't been registered for model "ModelName".Use mongoose.model(name, schema)'". Is there another way to populate one project's model, from another project's model?

Comment: show us any code to let us help you...

Comment: You can do it, but make sure schema for any collection is same in both projects, also field name should also be same.

Comment: @VinilPrabhu Thanks a lot, I implemented it the way you suggested, and it works!